# Connect whmcs to an old database

Tags: database, cpanel

I had a whmcs configured everything for a hosting, hundreds of domains extensions with prices each, web and hosting packages by year etc it took me many days to complete it.

One day my whmcs is not working and after so much work all I could do was reinstall it. 
Maybe is really easy but I tried many things and can't do it. I tried when install it softaculus tells you it will create a new database and I tried puting the old database name and user, but it does not work.

I see the database is in the cpanel, how can I connect it to my new WHMCS?